# Oceans of breathable liquid

Tags: planets, xenobiology, environment, ocean

I want to create a locale (hopefully a whole planet?), where the ocean is breathable. I was looking at perfluorocarbons, so the liquid part is at least possible(?)

Is there any way to create a world where the oceans might be like a natural version of perfluorocarbon or some other naturally occurring breathable liquid for humans?

I know that breathing the liquid is hard for the lungs to circulate in and out (and hypercapnia is an issue), but for now let’s focus on the environment. Thank you.

Edit: How about with a little handwavium?

Comment: The truth is, liquid breathing is still a relatively new area of study, and so I don't think I or very many people can give you a definitive answer with regards to this. Not to mention, I would imagine that some of the technology/research is classified, which would put a further throttle on any definitive, well know awnsers. That being a statement made right off.

Comment: just how "unbreathable" would seawater be, if the salt concentration is that of Neutral Saline, the water is highly oxygenated, and at a temperature of about 37C? I suspect the oxygen concentration will still be too low, and our lungs *really* don't do well with liquids, especially dirty liquids..  but still?

Comment: @PcMan - the problem with _that_ would be water.  Perfluorocarbons are useful for liquid "breathing" because they _can't_ be absorbed by tissues.  Even with perfect salinity, water transfer across cell walls would cause bad things to happen while in the water, and potential secondary drowning afterwards.

Comment: I don't know if editing this question is going to get me any further so I'm going to ask it again in a different way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue is that, while carbon is [pretty common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements) in the universe, being the 4th one for abundance in the Milky Way, fluorine is much more scarce.

Therefore making a whole ocean of perfluorocarbon seems highly unlikely, because with the known abundances it would be diluted in something much more available. And those are not equivalent to perfluorocarbons when it comes to breathing in them.

Comment: I read that fluoride is the 13th most abundant element on  Earth. Sounds pretty abundant. Its in the top 13! What if a planet that already had all the Carbon was bombarded by comets full of minerals that had a lot Fluorine in them? Yes? Maybe? No?